# TFS Sharepoint redirects "tfs.example.com/" to "SVTFS/default.aspx" (hostname)

Tags: sharepoint, redirect, team-foundation-server, wss

I've installed TFS 2008 and along with that came WSS (Sharepoint) 3.0. The server is located in a DMZ and has a hostname of "SVTFS". When the clients access it from the outside they use the fully qualified name "tfs.example.com".

Now, http://tfs.example.com/ is for the front page of the WSS server and it redirects to http://SVTFS/default.aspx. The SVTFS name is of course not accessible from outside the DMZ.

If I type http://tfs.example.com/default.aspx it loads just fine.

It's the same problem with project sites: http://tfs.example.com/sites/MyProject/ redirects to http://svtfs/sites/MyProject/default.aspx giving the user a DNS error.

Also, reports in the project pages tries to find the reporting server on http://svtfs/.

Anyone know how I can make WSS redirect to and use the fully qualified name instead of the local hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to open SP Central Administration > Operations > Alternate Access Mappings and add the internet URL of http://tfs.example.com/ in addition to of http://svtfs/

Answer (score 0):

*I had the same problem. You could do with making the question more generic, it took a bit of finding.*

[Walkthrough: Setting up Team Foundation Server with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and an ISAPI Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833872.aspx) provides step-by-step instructions and includes a section on alternate access mapping.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps it could be made more generic. I don't have any good ones now, maybe you have a suggestion so that I could edit it to be easier to find for others?